# Why are server's are so cheap on ebay with so much memory?

Tags: virtualization

I want to purchase a development machine and looking for it since ages, some are too expensive and some have not enough power to support (I need 3 VMware's atleast with Windows server 2008 r2 on them) 16 gb ram is must.

I look at dell and other websites, laptops and desktops are very expensive but server's are cheaper then them.

however on ebay server's are sooo cheap that i can't believe them.

I am not advertising anything but don't you think it's a cheap server with so much memory,

http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/HP-DL360-G5-Twin-Quad-Core-Xeon-2-33Ghz-16GB-RAM-VT-x64-ProLiant-Server-VMware/400483739423?_trksid=p2047675.m2109&_trkparms=aid%3D555001%26algo%3DPW.CURRENT%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D15989%26meid%3D8470632461398566447%26pid%3D100010%26prg%3D7588%26rk%3D4%26sd%3D271222826838%26

when if i buy a desktop or laptop with same specs i need to pay atleast 1500 $.

Comment: No hard drives. SAS drives are EXTREMELY expensive and take up a good chunk of the total cost of any server. Note that this is an off topic question.

Comment: That item is used, plain and simple. Dell and other websites sell brand new computers.

Comment: That's a [6 year old processor](http://ark.intel.com/products/28032/) . . . any hardware that old will obviously be cheap.

Comment: @tereško - If you want used buy used if you want new you have to pay the difference. Furthermore what you are finding on Ebay was three generations ago.

Comment: Maybe you should rephrase your question. It has a lot of negative votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I don't think this is the right site for this question, and your question is rather vague, I'm going to try to help answer you or at least provide some insight.

I roll G5s in my home data center and they work very well. However 16GB isn't really a whole lot of RAM for a server to run, you should get 32GB if possible. You're going to run out of RAM on a VM server way before CPU.

If you want to buy SAS, you can buy SAS, but no one is buying SAS anymore, mostly everyone is moving to SSD. And for home applications you can use SATA IIIs on any of the HPs that support SAS. You can buy SATA 2.5 laptop drives for around $70 for a 750GB drive. Which means you can have a 1+0 RAID disk pool for less than $400 (USD) that gives you 2TB over 6 hard drive arms. Should be plenty enough for a few VM servers.

If you can find the L5450 CPUs they're pretty good. They have good performance but are designed to use less power (most servers sit and do nothing 80% of the time - this is the basis behind virtualzation).

You can only support the full 6 drives if you have the P400 controller, which that one has, which is good. You'll need drive trays which run about $10 each. Most people don't give them to you.

If you can, look to get the DL380s, they are 2U, but you can stack 8 drives, handle better CPUs and (I believe) more RAM. I only have one DL380, but it seems to have more horsepower than the DL360s I have. The G5 generation of servers is really the first generation of servers where you can run vCenter/vSphere/ESXi and have a 64-bit VM.

These servers may seem cheap, and comparatively they are, but in the long run, if you spec them out with 6 or 8 hard drives, more RAM, replace fans and other components, it will end up costing you more than double. That doesn't mean you shouldn't buy it. I think HP servers are the best you can get.

Finally, these servers are loud. You wouldn't want to put them in the same room where you are working. When they first start up they're like a plane taking off, but after they settle down and pass POST testing, they quiet down. However, even then the fans can be a bit loud. Just keep this in mind. Good luck.